# How can I get the ItemRenderer of a Flex Spark List from its DataProvider Object?

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, dataprovider, flex-spark

In Flex I can create an ItemRenderer to represent each item in the Lists DataProvider but how do I access the instance of the ItemRenderer via the DataProviders Object? Something like `myList.getItemRenderer(dp.getItemAt(10));`

Comment: Since a Flex list recycles its item renderers by default, you won't be able to reliably access an item renderer for a given data object.  There might not even be a renderer associated with the data object if it is scrolled outside of the viewable area of the list.  What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 15):

```
public function getItemRenderer(list:List, item:Object):ItemRenderer
{
    var dataGroup:DataGroup = list.dataGroup;
    var n:int = dataGroup.numElements;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var renderer:ItemRenderer = dataGroup.getElementAt(i) as ItemRenderer;
        if (renderer && renderer.data == item)
            return renderer;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: For this to work all the time, you need to set the List's useVirtualLayout to false. That way, all ItemRenderers will be created even if they aren't visible. With useVirtualLayout true, some ItemRenderers will only be created when they are visible.

Answer (score 1):

By using this method, you cannot get the renderer that is outside of the viewable area and there will also be a lot of other issues.

Comment: You're correct. I've unselected the previous answer but would be great to find a solution for this.

Comment: There's no "right" answer for this questions since Flex SDK does not support direct renderer access by data.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change how the item renderer is behaving, change the data that is causing the behavior.

```
var items:ArrayCollection = this.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
    var newItems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    if (items.length > 0) {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item:Object = items[i] as Object;

            if (!item.editMode) {
                item.editMode = true;
            } else {
                item.editMode = false;
            }

            newItems.addItem(item);
        }
    }

    this.dataProvider = null;
    this.dataProvider = newItems;
```

This is a simple example where the I mark items to be deletable and the renderer changes according since the data has been changed.  For larger data sets, I understand this can be a little slow but it gives you the control you are after.

If you need to change one renderer, simply modify the data on the corresponding object in the dataProvider or dataGroup.

```
var item:Object = this.getItemAt(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but perhaps it will help someone:

```
var item:ItemRenderer = list.dataGroup.getElementAt(0) as ItemRenderer;
```

That will give you the ItemRenderer, if you have a custom IR then just use that class and cast and your set.